# Как импортировать данные

Tags: sql

С помощью какой команды, в sql server, можно перенести БД из одного server-а на другой server?

Answer (score 2):

Командами backup / restore

Answer (score 1):

надо экспорт дампа БД

> Выгружаем SQL базу в файл:

```
 mysqldump имябазыданных -u
> user_name_db -ppassword_db -h IP (или
> localhost) > db_name.sql
```

> Загружаем SQL базу из файла:
>
> ```
> > mysql имябазыданных -u user_name_db
> > -ppassword_db < db_name.sql
> ```

Comment: не понятно,как ето делать

Comment: А сервер-то какой? А то их много, хороших и разных...

Comment: Принято считать (в моей среде), что это MS SQL Server

Comment: для MS SQL есть куча утилит

Comment: у меня MS SQL 2008 R2.

Comment: Извините, не по теме. Подсказать решение не могу, но комментарий @renegator понравился. Видимо вопрошающие должны ещё и указывать среду обитания.

Comment: Если база небольшая и данных в ней не много , то в SQL Server тоже есть возможность генерации скрипта создания бд, с последующим занесением имеющихся данных. А если она большая то как правильно написал @Modus через бекап.

Comment: добавлю еще пару возможностей - через detach/attach, старый добрый DTS

насчет названия и среды. "SQL Server" в названии есть только у MS SQL Server. А до этого - только у Sybase SQL Server, от которого и происходит продукт MS SQL Server. Собственно самый первый сервер, который Microsoft сделали в сотрудничестве с авторами dBase незабвенной Aston-Tate так и назывался SQL Server 1.0
Насчет среды - многие web-разработчики вообще не в курсе . что существует что-то кроме MySQL